# Labeling shape on plotly js

Tags: plot, graph, label, plotly, plotly.js

I've been trying to add different colored shapes to the background of plotly.js. However, I also want to be able to label them somewhere so the user knows what color has what meaning. How can I do that?

The first example on here is basically what I've got so far:
https://plot.ly/javascript/shapes/